# Merging tags [antispam] and [anti-spam]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Currently there are two identical tags: [[antispam]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antispam) and [[anti-spam]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam). I think they should be merged, since there is no real difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge is complete with [anti-spam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam) as the master tag.